# Interface Segregation Principle: How to split big interface with a lot of optional methods

Tags: php, interface, solid-principles, interface-segregation-principle

Suppose I have an interface:

```php
interface WorkerInterface
{
    public function doCommonAction1(CommonAction1Params $params): CommonAction1Result;

    public function doCommonAction2(CommonAction2Params $params): CommonAction2Result;

    /**
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws UnsupportedMethodException
     */
    public function doSpecificAction1(SpecificAction1Params $params): SpecificAction1Result;

    /**
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws UnsupportedMethodException
     */
    public function doSpecificAction2(SpecificAction2Params $params): SpecificAction2Result;
}
```

The problem is that methods `doSpecificAction1` and `doSpecificAction2` are optional and supported not by all workers. Worker can support `doCommonAction1` and `doCommonAction2` only, as well as `doCommonAction1`, `doCommonAction2` and `doSpecificAction1`, or `doCommonAction1`, `doCommonAction2`, `doSpecificAction2`, or all methods together.

Also I have a WorkerFactory:

```php
class WorkerFactory
{
    public function createWorker(string $workerId): WorkerInterface
    {
        // worker is created here
    }
}
```

Then I have a controller:

```php
class ActionController {
    public function commonAction1(string $workerId, WorkerFactory $factory)
    {
        $worker = $factory->createWorker($workerId);

        $worker->doCommonAction1(new CommonAction1Params());
    }

    public function commonAction2(string $workerId, WorkerFactory $factory)
    {
        $worker = $factory->createWorker($workerId);

        $worker->doCommonAction2(new CommonAction2Params());
    }

    public function specificAction1(string $workerId, WorkerFactory $factory)
    {
        $worker = $factory->createWorker($workerId);

        try {
            $worker->doSpecificAction1(new SpecificAction1Params());
        } catch (UnsupportedMethodException $e) {
            // do something
        }
    }

    public function specificAction2(string $workerId, WorkerFactory $factory)
    {
        $worker = $factory->createWorker($workerId);

        try {
            $worker->doSpecificAction2(new SpecificAction2Params());
        } catch (UnsupportedMethodException $e) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

It's obvious that now my code violates Interface Segregation Principle. I would like to refactor it.
OK, I try doing something like this:

```php
interface WorkerInterface
{
    public function doCommonAction1(CommonAction1Params $params): CommonAction1Result;

    public function doCommonAction2(CommonAction2Params $params): CommonAction2Result;
}

interface SpecificAction1AwareInterface
{
    public function doSpecificAction1(SpecificAction1Params $params): SpecificAction1Result;
}

interface SpecificAction2AwareInterface
{
    public function doSpecificAction2(SpecificAction2Params $params): SpecificAction2Result;
}
```

So now my workers will look like this:

```php
class Worker1 implements WorkerInterface {}

class Worker2 implements WorkerInterface, SpecificAction1AwareInterface {}

class Worker3 implements WorkerInterface, SpecificAction1AwareInterface, SpecificAction2AwareInterface {}
```

And now my controller changes to this:

```php
class ActionController {
    public function commonAction1(string $workerId, WorkerFactory $factory)
    {
        $worker = $factory->createWorker($workerId);

        $worker->doCommonAction1(new CommonAction1Params());
    }

    public function commonAction2(string $workerId, WorkerFactory $factory)
    {
        $worker = $factory->createWorker($workerId);

        $worker->doCommonAction2(new CommonAction2Params());
    }

    public function specificAction1(string $workerId, WorkerFactory $factory)
    {
        $worker = $factory->createWorker($workerId);

        if ($worker instanceof SpecificAction1AwareInterface) {
            $worker->doSpecificAction1(new SpecificAction1Params());
        } else {
            // do something
        }
    }

    public function specificAction2(string $workerId, WorkerFactory $factory)
    {
        $worker = $factory->createWorker($workerId);

        if ($worker instanceof SpecificAction2AwareInterface) {
            $worker->doSpecificAction1(new SpecificAction2Params());
        } else {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

But this code seems ugly I think. I'm not sure that using instanceof is a good idea especially because `SpecificAction1AwareInterface` and `SpecificAction2AwareInterface` aren't related to `WorkerInterface` at all.

So are there any design patterns suitable for my situation? Thank you in advance.